# Match Regular Expressoin if string contains exactly N occrences of a character

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I'd like a regular expression to match a string only if it contains a character that occurs a predefined number of times.

For example:
I want to match all strings that contain the character "_" 3 times;

So
"a_b_c_d" would pass
"a_b" would fail
"a_b_c_d_e" would fail

Does someone know a simple regular expression that would satisfy this?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your example, you could do:

```
\b[a-z]*(_[a-z]*){3}[a-z]*\b
```

(with an ignore case flag).

You can play with it [here](http://regexr.com?3019n)

It says "match 0 or more letters, followed by '_[a-z]*' exactly three times, followed by 0 or more letters". The `\b` means "word boundary", ie "match a whole word".

Since I've used '*' this will match if there are exactly three "_" in the word regardless of whether it appears at the start or end of the word - you can modify it otherwise.

Also, I've assumed you want to match all words in a string with exactly three "_" in it.

That means the string "a_b a_b_c_d" would say that "a_b_c_d" passed (but "a_b" fails).

If you mean that *globally* across the *entire string* you only want three "_" to appear, then use:

```
^[^_]*(_[^_]*){3}[^_]*$
```

This anchors the regex at the start of the string and goes to the end, making sure there are only three occurences of "_" in it.

Comment: \b[a-z]*(_[a-z]*){3}[a-z]*\b is exactly what I needed.  Great!

Comment: Beware that this will work only if underscores are separated by lowercase alphabetic characters (i.e. letters).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
^[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Rado's answer, which is so far the most polyvalent but could be a pain to write if there are more occurrences to match :

```
^([^_]*_){3}[^_]*$
```

It will match entire strings (from the beginning `^` to the end `$`) in which there are exactly 3 (`{3}`) times the pattern consisting of 0 or more (`*`) times any character not being underscore (`[^_]`) and one underscore (`_`), the whole being followed by 0 ore more times any character other than underscore (`[^_]*`, again).

Of course one could alternatively group the other way round, as in our case the pattern is symmetric :

```
^[^_]*(_[^_]*){3}$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're examples are the only possibilities (like a_b_c_...), then the others are fine, but I wrote one that will handle some other possibilities. Such as:

```
a__b_adf
a_b_asfdasdfasfdasdfasf_asdfasfd
___
_a_b_b
```

Etc.

Here's my regex.

```
\b(_[^_]*|[^_]*_|_){3}\b
```